# Unique values of a dataframe column to list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, unique

I have an R table (site_df). Need to convert unique values from a column (site_name) to a list. Any suggestions?

Example:

```
site_list = site_df %>% unique(site_name) %>% convert this to list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can get `unique` values from `site_name` and make it a list.

```
as.list(unique(site_df$site_name))
```

For example, with default `mtcars` this will result into :

```
as.list(unique(mtcars$cyl))
#[[1]]
#[1] 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 4

#[[3]]
#[1] 8
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get the `distinct` elements of the column, `pull` that column as  a `vector` and convert to a `list` with `as.list`

```
library(dplyr)
site_df %>%
   distinct(site_name) %>%
   pull(site_name) %>%
   as.list
```